# Why can't I use the delete function of SQLiteDatabase on Android

Tags: android-sqlite

I'm trying to use the `delete` function of `SQLiteDataBase` to delete my data, but it always shows me **Unfortunately**.

This is my method:

```
private void del(){

        String id = editId.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID + "=" + id, null);

        cleanEditText();
    }
```

However, if I use `db.execSQL("DELETE from friends");` instead of the `delete` function, it works, and deletes all the data.

How can I make the `delete` function work?

```
The LogCat say the following:
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Adam: , while compiling: DELETE FROM friends WHERE _id=Adam
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:266)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1747)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at com.tonycube.demo.SQLiteDemoActivity.del(SQLiteDemoActivity.java:163)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at com.tonycube.demo.SQLiteDemoActivity.onClick(SQLiteDemoActivity.java:86)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
11-29 23:55:02.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29207):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the Helper:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "demo.db";
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String INIT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                                  _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                  NAME + " CHAR, " +
                                  TEL + " CHAR, " +
                                  EMAIL + " CHAR);"; 
        db.execSQL(INIT_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Then, this is my click function:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            add();
            break;

        case R.id.btnDel:
            del();
            break;

        case R.id.btnUpdate:
            update();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        show();
        showInList();
    }
```

The result will be this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mslk0.png

Comment: Isn't it `DROP` instead of `DELETE`?

Comment: Are you sure, you have the right content in `TABLE_NAME`? Also, you should use the third parameter of `delete` (`whereArgs`) to supply parameters that are provided by the user (see Prepared Statements).

Comment: I have used Log.d to check that the id and _ID are correct.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm trying to use the delete function of SQLiteDataBase to delete my data, but it always show me" -- always shows you what? What error (if any) do you get when you run your code?

Here's an example of using delete:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID + " = ?", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
```

You should always used parameterised queries to help mitigate SQL injection attacks.

You say `db.execSQL("DELETE from friends");` works but this is a completely different query and doesn't select by ID -- perhaps your `_ID` constant is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give accurate information.
The _ID is from **import static android.provider.BaseColumns._ID**, and I said the app always crash on the delete function.

Comment: You error makes it very clear -- _ID must be an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID + "=" + id, null);
```

with the following line

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID + "=" + "'"+id+"'", null);
```

Let me know the result

Comment: This would be correct if he had used db.execSQL(SQL statement)

Comment: `import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public interface DbConstants extends BaseColumns {
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends";
 
 public static final String NAME = "name";
 public static final String TEL = "tel";
 public static final String EMAIL = "email";
}`

Comment: post the schema not this constant value

Comment: Here in this editText you need to put the _ID of the table.
String _id = editId.getText().toString(); [Put a exsisting _ID of your friend table , Don't put friend name as ur _ID is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ] . Then type cast ur String _id int0 int
int id = Integer.ParseInt(_Id);

Comment: Now u can use this db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID + "=" + id, null);

Comment: I make id to be an integer, but i still crash when i press the delete button.